# Display Lat Lng Coordinates on click on Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, onclick, coordinates, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to get my mapbox to display coordinates [like this Google Map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-click-latlng), with a popup of lat lng coordinates on click. The closest I have gotten is getting a draggable marker which displays the coordinates at the bottom left of the map, if I tried an onclick function, the map just goes blank. How could I get the coordinates to appear as a popup on click?

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
        draggable: true
    })
    .setLngLat([101.967, 35.431])
    .addTo(map);

function onDragEnd() {
    var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();

    coordinates.style.display = 'block';
    coordinates.innerHTML =
        'Longitude: ' + lngLat.lng + '<br />Latitude: ' + lngLat.lat;
}

marker.on('dragend', onDragEnd);
```

And I have css styles for .coordinates for them to display at the bottom left of the screen when the marker is dragged around.
I know this is a simple question, but I'm totally new to mapbox and coding in general. Would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a Mapbox [Popup](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup)

I have drafted a quick [fiddle on how to create a popup with the coordinates clicked](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/wm4d3tf2/8/), and here you have the relevant js code:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PUT HERE YOUR TOKEN';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [-122.486052, 37.830348],
  zoom: 14
});
map.on('style.load', function() {
  map.on('click', function(e) {
    var coordinates = e.lngLat;
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
      .setLngLat(coordinates)
      .setHTML('you clicked here: <br/>' + coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! if it solved your issue, please mark it as **answer accepted** in that way it will also help other users with the same issue to know it was the right solution

Comment: Very good. And how do i put these coordinates inside an input form? For example, in the Lat input, insert the latitude values ​​and in the Lng input, insert the longitude values ​​when clicked on the map?

Comment: @MichelXavier I'd recommend you to open a new question on that topic as it's definitely a different one.

Comment: @jscastro, thanks for your feedback. Actually i opened a question similar with this one. I'm just try to find some similar doubt related with my question. if you can help me, I appreciate :) ..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274012/mapbox-how-to-display-lat-and-lng-coordinates-inside-a-div-after-select-addres .... thanks.

Comment: @MichelXavier, I just replied to your question.

Comment: @jscastro, i saw your solution and works for me. Thanks a lot :)