# MapBox - How to display lat and lng coordinates inside a div after select address inside a list

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using MapBox on my application and i would like to know how can i display lat and lng inside div element after i select an address from a list that are display inside a div? My reference is this MapBox page https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-no-map/, but i didn't find a correct way to do that using javascript.

To explain more clearly my doubt, below are the code that i'm using on my application and i would like to display lat and lng inside "latitude" and "longitude" div's as below if is possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Use the geocoder without a map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.5.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.5.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css"
    type="text/css"
/>
<!-- Promise polyfill script required to use Mapbox GL Geocoder in IE 11 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #geocoder {
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        top: 20px;
    }
    .mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="geocoder"></div>

//How to display latitude and longitude inside div element below after select a value inside geocoder div above?

<div id="latitude">
<div id="longitude">

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiM3dzdG9yZSIsImEiOiJja2RoaWVlaGwyc2VxMnlwbWVrd2F2bmVoIn0.YNjkfQ-709GuxaE4vOjsxg';
    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        types: 'country,region,place,postcode,locality,neighborhood'
    });

    geocoder.addTo('#geocoder');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case, how can i improve the code above to display latitude and longitude informations inside a div after select a value inside geocoder div?

Comment: You need to demonstrate what you have actually tried, and where you got stuck. This currently reads like "here's what I want, please write my code".

Comment: @SteveBennett , sorry about that. it was not my intention to try to force someone to help. I edited the code above and i'm having difficult to showing latitude and longitude in a div field after selecting the value inside geocoder div. In this case, how can i improve my code to display these informations inside a div after select a value inside geocode div? Thanks for your attention and sorry again.

Comment: Which part are you stuck with? Accessing the lat and long? Or displaying information in a div?

Comment: @SteveBennett, in this case i would like to display information in a div after select address inside #geocoder div. On code above, i commented the code next latitude and longitude div's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you well, what you want is basically capture the result selected in the geocoder and paint the coordinates of the result in a div. For that, you need to subscribe to the `result` event.

For that, you need to add the event listener like this, and there paint the result in the inner HTML of the div:

```js
    geocoder.on('result', function(r) {
      console.log(r);
      document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = r.result.center;
    })
```

I have created a [fiddle on how to subscribe to result selected on geocoder](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/1L3y68r5/5/)

[image]

PS: If this answer solves your question, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way it will help other users to know is the right solution.